# How to wait till all the users respond to google form programmatically through google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am new to google script. I need to create a google form every week and once all the users (10 users) respond to the form, we need to update a master excel sheet. I am able to create form and when a user responds, I am able to write the response to a spreadsheet. But I am not sure how to wait till all the users respond and update master excel sheet.

**Code:**

```
function createForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('dummy').setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true);
    
  item = "Name";
  form.addTextItem().setTitle(item).setRequired(true);
    
  var choices = ["cat", "dog"];
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("choice").setChoiceValues(choices).setRequired(true);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("response_sheet");
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve the below things.

1. Write now I am updating response_sheet when a user responds. Once all the users respond, I need to update a master excel sheet. I am not sure how to wait till all the users respond.
2. Is there a way to shorten form's published url through google script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the number of responses is static, you can have the script check to see if the number of rows of data is equal to the number of expected responses using [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()). Otherwise, if you have a list of responder email addresses, you can use that to make sure each email address is accounted for.
   For example:

```
     if (lastRow % 10 == 0){
        updateMasterSheet();
     }
```

2. You want to use [shortenFormUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#shortenFormUrl(String)) to get the short version of the form url to share.